# Fecha en Django Admin

Tags: python, django, date, django-admin

Hola gente no puedo dar con la solución, en en una clase que muestro en el Admin de django un campo es fecha y cuando el admin lo muestra usa el formato tipo '1 de agosto del 2021' pero necesito que muestre 'Agosto 2021' y no puedo encontrar como modificar eso.
Probé con lo siguiente:

```
def fecha_mes(self, obj):
  return obj.fecha.strftime("%B %Y")
end
```

Y agregando *fecha_mes* al list_display pero me lo muestra en ingles al mes.

El **settings.py** lo tengo asi:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-es'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Cordoba'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloca lo siguiente en tu archivo admin.py para cambiar el formato predeterminado de fecha en el administrador de django.

```
from django.conf.locale.es import formats as es_formats

es_formats.DATETIME_FORMAT = "F Y"
```

Cambiará los formatos de fecha de tu ModelAdmin en ese archivo. No rompe los filtros de fecha y hora del administrador.

A mi me sirvió, espero que te sirva.